# Find which Table in SQL Join takes more time to execute?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

In Stored Procedure, I have used many inner joins and when I execute my SP, it takes more than one hour.

I am assuming that one particular table cause this problem.

**I would like to find out joining which table takes more time.**

I tried Query Execution Plan but I expect something other than QEP. Please suggest me.

Comment: please post query you are using,tables involved and execution plan as xml..in simple terms post an MVCE

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Check the execution plan. That's the only thing that will tell you what is going on, and how long each step takes. It can also *suggest* any missing indexes

Comment: As for `I expect something other than QEP` like what? This shows you all the information, in a graphical way, with the expensive parts *very clearly* marked. Follow the fat lines. Find and remove the table scans by adding indexes

Comment: In general, if you want help with a query you have to post first and foremost the execution plan. Then come the query text, row sizes and the schema of the tables. Sometimes the query does something dumb, like aggregating everything then trying to filter out some rows. In most cases though you need to check the execution plan

Comment: It depends of your machine, RAM sql server version and number records in table with proper index. You can skip tables one by one to identify the table which you want.

Comment: Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Answer (score -1):

Using Joins in SQL always takes more time. Check whether tables have proper Index. Only specify the columns in inner join select list.

Ex. 
Select A.* from Table1 A
inner join(Select ID from Table2) B
on A.Id = B.Id

Comment: That's not correct. The optimizer will only use the columns it needs. You gain absolutely nothing with the subquery. And joins don't "always take more time". The optimizer is smart enough to create the same execution plan most of the time, for queries with different syntax (eg JOIN vs subquery) as long as they are logically equivalent. It's processing more rows that takes more time